# Overlap data raster with shape file coordinate system

Tags: r, shapefile

I have a dataframe that contains the geometry of the shape file for South America, I want overlap this shpfile with a dataframe of PM2.5 data raster of the same domain. However, when I do so the 2 maps doesn't correspond. So I think there is something wrong with non-corresponding coordinate systems. Does someone know how to solve this?
This is my code:

```
library(ncdf4)
library(lubridate)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(chron)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

color_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"))(100)


shapefile_path <- "C:/Users/littl/South_America/South_America.shp"
south_america <- st_read(shapefile_path)
# Controlla il sistema di coordinate del shapefile
st_crs(south_america)

# Se il sistema di coordinate dello shapefile non corrisponde alla mappa, esegui la trasformazione
# Ad esempio, se la tua mappa ha il sistema di coordinate WGS 84 (EPSG:4326), puoi eseguire:
if (st_crs(south_america)$epsg != 4326) {
south_america <- st_transform(south_america, crs = 4326)
}


# Assicurati di inserire il percorso corretto al file "yearmean_levtype_sfc.nc"
file_path <- "C:/Users/littl/yearmean_levtype_sfc.nc"
nc_file <- nc_open(file_path)
nc_file
#Estrai la prima banda di dati (pm2p5)
pm2p5_data <- ncvar_get(nc_file, "pm2p5", start = c(1, 1, 1), count = c(-1, -1, 1)) 
#start = c(1, 1, 1) specifica che la lettura dei dati deve iniziare alla prima posizione delle tre dimensioni (longitude, latitude, time).
#count = c(-1, -1, 1) indica che vogliamo leggere tutti gli elementi delle prime due dimensioni (longitude e latitude) e solo la prima banda di dati nella dimensione "time". Il valore "-1" in count per le prime due dimensioni significa "leggi tutti gli elementi".
pm2p5_data
# Chiudi il file NetCDF dopo aver estratto i dati
nc_close(nc_file)
# Puoi convertire i dati in un data frame
lon <- seq(-90, -20, length.out = dim(pm2p5_data)[1])
lat <- seq(20, -60, length.out = dim(pm2p5_data)[2])
df <- expand.grid(lon = lon, lat = lat)
#df$lat <- rev(df$lat)
#df$lon <- rev(df$lon)
df$pm2p5 <- as.vector(pm2p5_data)
ggplot() +
geom_raster(data = df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = pm2p5)) +
scale_fill_gradientn(colors = color_palette) + # Use the color_palette color scale
geom_sf(data = south_america, fill = "transparent", color = "black", size = 0.5) +
labs(title = "Annual mean PM2.5, 2010",
     x = "Longitudine",
     y = "Latitudine",
     fill = "PM2.5 (kg m^-3)") +
theme_minimal()
```

Details South_America.shp:

```
south_america
Simple feature collection with 15 features and 1 field
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -109.4461 ymin: -58.49861 xmax: -26.24139 ymax: 12.59028
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
First 10 features:
                  COUNTRY                       geometry
1               Argentina MULTIPOLYGON (((-71.01648 -...
2                 Bolivia MULTIPOLYGON (((-62.19884 -...
3                  Brazil MULTIPOLYGON (((-70.62862 -...
4                   Chile MULTIPOLYGON (((-73.61806 -...
5                Colombia MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.71306 1...
6                 Ecuador MULTIPOLYGON (((-78.70903 -...
7  French Guiana (France) MULTIPOLYGON (((-54.60378 2...
8   Falkland Islands (UK) MULTIPOLYGON (((-59.79139 -...
9                  Guyana MULTIPOLYGON (((-60.08087 5...
10               Suriname MULTIPOLYGON (((-54.09445 3...
```

Details of the pm2.5 file:

```
File C:/Users/littl/yearmean_levtype_sfc.nc (NC_FORMAT_64BIT):

     2 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        double time_bnds[bnds,time]   
        short pm2p5[longitude,latitude,time]   
            standard_name: mass_concentration_of_pm2p5_ambient_aerosol_particles_in_air
            long_name: Particulate matter d <= 2.5 um
            units: kg m**-3
            add_offset: 2.38108791659124e-06
            scale_factor: 7.26694719096392e-11
            _FillValue: -32767
            missing_value: -32767
            cell_methods: time: mean

     4 dimensions:
        time  Size:10   *** is unlimited *** 
            standard_name: time
            long_name: time
            bounds: time_bnds
            units: hours since 1900-01-01 00:00:00.0
            calendar: gregorian
            axis: T
        bnds  Size:2 (no dimvar)
        longitude  Size:69 
            standard_name: longitude
            long_name: longitude
            units: degrees_east
            axis: X
        latitude  Size:94 
            standard_name: latitude
            long_name: latitude
            units: degrees_north
            axis: Y

    5 global attributes:
        CDI: Climate Data Interface version 2.0.4 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)
        Conventions: CF-1.6
        history: Wed Jul 19 14:23:12 2023: cdo yearmean levtype_sfc.nc yearmean_levtype_sfc.nc
2023-07-18 14:07:17 GMT by grib_to_netcdf-2.25.1: /opt/ecmwf/mars-client/bin/grib_to_netcdf.bin -S param -o /cache/tmp/048068bd-b521-42fe-a5ff-0d5e1fe2fe60-adaptor.mars.internal-1689689093.9330037-19537-15-tmp.nc /cache/tmp/048068bd-b521-42fe-a5ff-0d5e1fe2fe60-adaptor.mars.internal-1689682802.5415428-19537-11-tmp.grib
        frequency: year
        CDO: Climate Data Operators version 2.0.4 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)
```

My output:
[image]

The output with qGis:
[image]

Comment: Please help reproduce the issue by supplying sample data or linking to the sources of South_America.shp and yearmean_levtype_sfc.nc , and specifying how the maps don't correspond (preferably with a plot of the misaligned features). https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I add what you ask!

Comment: The plot is already helpful, thank you! With "sources" I meant the URLs where you (probably) obtained vector data (shp) and raster data (nc) from. (I understand those are too large to `dput` here, but to trace the bug - if any - your workflow has to be reproducible without access to your local data. That said, the hotspots of PM2.5 coincide with Santiago, Rio and Maraba quite well, give or take some atmospheric transport along the main wind directions.

Comment: oh ok sorry, so the url for the shpfile is: https://www.efrainmaps.es/english-version/free-downloads/south-america/

Comment: But for the raster I download the Copernicus data from: ads.atmosphere.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/… –  and then I used cdo yearmean to calculate Annual mean for every single year of my interest (from 2010 to 2019)

Comment: Copernicus data url: https://ads.atmosphere.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/cams-global-reanalysis-eac4?tab=overview

Comment: Sorry if I add another comment but I've try with qgis and here boundaries are differnet from the plot with Rstudio, I add the picture also

Comment: I would still have to get an account to download the NetCDF. Anyhow: maybe it helps to explicitly specify the coordinate system used by ggplot via `ggplot() + ... + coord_sf(...)`. (See `?coord_sf`).

Comment: explicitly specify: WGS84